# Error al intentar coger una array en Firebase RealTIme

Tags: firebase, kotlin, realtime-database, database-android

Tengo el problema que cuando intento coger una array de firebase realtime, no me entra al método, no se si hago mal algo.

En firebase tengo esta array

[image: Array en firebase]

Intento de coger los datos de la siguiente manera :

```
  fun getFirebaseCategory() {
        categorias = ArrayList()
        val database = Firebase.database.reference
        Log.d("Categorias", "En categorias")
        database.child("categorias").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    categorias.add(snapshot.getValue(String::class.java)!!)
                    categorias.forEach {
                        Log.d("Categorias", "la lista de categorias es : $it")   
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("Categorias", "Error : loadPost:onCancelled $error")
            }
        })
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que me entra en el primer log(En categorías) pero en los demás no.

Answer (score 0):

están bien los métodos, el fallo se debe a que han de importar implementaciones adicionales en el Gradle

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:23.0.0'
```